# Membership registration required fields

Tags: members

Is there a way to prevent the username being a required field for membership registration. Or use the email field to jointly populate the username field? I'm using the Simple Registration addon to create a front end form.

Answer (score 2):

When you disable the Username field in the Form Settings tab, Simple Registration will use email address for the username.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, don't know how I missed that one!

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, can click that checkmark and accept it as the correct answer?